# Find out GIT repo from PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I was asked to help with an old project. It appears the project was originally using a GIT repository either on Bitbucket or GitHub, but nobody knows. I have access to PhpStorm that has it still mapped.

How can I figure out in PhpStorm which repo was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the Git root location at File | Settings | Version Control. Then open it, and find the .git/config file (.git folder is typically hidden). 
Remote repositories should be listed there.